# German Umlauts with Symfony 3.4 Swiftmailer

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

If I send a text/plain or html mail with Symfony's (3.4) SwiftMailer, Thunderbird does not display the german umlauts correct.

All my sources are UTF-8 encoded.

```
        $message = (new \Swift_Message($this->subject))
        ->setFrom($this->sender)
        ->setSender($this->sender)
        ->setTo($this->recipient)
        ->setSubject($this->subject)
        ->setBody('Test öäüß','text/html');

    $this->mailer->send($message);
```

The subject seems ok, but the content is wrong:

Thunderbird shows: Test Ã¶Ã¤Ã¼ÃŸ

Mail Source:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="_=_swift_v4_1515967254_0cffc8849a46a198af559bc5915f8780_=_"
X-Swift-To: root@localhost
X-Swift-To: root@localhost

--_=_swift_v4_1515967254_0cffc8849a46a198af559bc5915f8780_=_
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Test =C3=B6=C3=A4=C3=BC=C3=9F

--_=_swift_v4_1515967254_0cffc8849a46a198af559bc5915f8780_=_
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

    Test =C3=B6=C3=A4=C3=BC=C3=9F


--_=_swift_v4_1515967254_0cffc8849a46a198af559bc5915f8780_=_--
```

So, the charset seems correkt, but what is my mistake?